# Unable to implement autopopulate from typeahead. What mistake am I making here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, autocomplete, twitter-typeahead

I am trying to use twitter's typeahead for auto populating country list, but nothing happens when I start typing in:

The following is a self calling function.

```
var Countries = function() {

var typeAheadCDN = "https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js";

var countryList = [
                'Afghanistan','Albania','Algeria','American Samoa','Andorra','Angola','Anguilla','Antigua and Barbuda','Argentina','Armenia','Aruba','Australia','Austria','Azerbaijan',
                'The Bahamas','Bahrain','Bangladesh','Barbados','Belarus','Belgium','Belize','Benin','Bermuda','Bhutan','Bolivia','Bosnia and Herzegovina','Botswana','Brazil','British Virgin Islands',
                'Brunei','Bulgaria','Burkina Faso','Burundi','Cambodia','Cameroon','Canada','Cape Verde','Cayman Islands','Central African Republic','Chad','Chile','China','Christmas Island',
                'Cocos Islands','Colombia','Comoros','Cook Islands','Costa Rica','Côte d\'Ivoire','Croatia','Cuba','Curaçao','Cyprus','Czech Republic','Democratic Republic of the Congo',
                'Denmark','Djibouti','Dominica','Dominican Republic','East Timor','Ecuador','Egypt','El Salvador','Equatorial Guinea','Eritrea','Estonia','Ethiopia','Falkland Islands',
                'Faroe Islands','Fiji','Finland','France','French Guiana','French Polynesia','Gabon','The Gambia','Georgia','Germany','Ghana','Gibraltar','Greece','Greenland','Grenada',
                'Guadeloupe','Guam','Guatemala','Guernsey','Guinea','Guinea-Bissau','Guyana','Haiti','Honduras','Hong Kong','Hungary','Iceland','India','Indonesia','Iran','Iraq','Ireland',
                'Isle of Man','Israel','Italy','Jamaica','Japan','Jersey','Jordan','Kazakhstan','Kenya','Kiribati','Kosovo','Kuwait','Kyrgyzstan','Laos','Latvia','Lebanon','Lesotho','Liberia',
                'Libya','Liechtenstein','Lithuania','Luxembourg','Macedonia','Madagascar','Malawi','Malaysia','Maldives','Mali','Malta','Marshall Islands','Martinique','Mauritania','Mauritius',
                'Mayotte','Mexico','Federated States of Micronesia','Moldova','Monaco','Mongolia','Montenegro','Montserrat','Morocco','Mozambique','Myanmar','Nagorno-Karabakh','Namibia','Nauru',
                'Nepal','Netherlands','New Caledonia','New Zealand','Nicaragua','Niger','Nigeria','Niue','Norfolk Island','North Korea','Northern Cyprus','Northern Mariana Islands','Norway',
                'Oman','Pakistan','Palau','Panama','Papua New Guinea','Paraguay','Peru','Philippines','Pitcairn Islands','Poland','Portugal','Puerto Rico','Qatar','Republic of the Congo',
                'Réunion','Romania','Russia','Rwanda','Sahrawi Arab Democratic Republic','Saint Barthélemy','Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha','Saint Kitts and Nevis','Saint Martin',
                'Saint Lucia','Saint Pierre and Miquelon','Saint Vincent and the Grenadines','Samoa','San Marino','São Tomé and Príncipe','Saudi Arabia','Senegal','Serbia','Seychelles','Sierra Leone',
                'Singapore','Sint Maarten','Slovakia','Slovenia','Solomon Islands','Somalia','South Africa','South Korea','South Sudan','Spain','Sri Lanka','Sudan','Suriname','Svalbard','Swaziland',
                'Sweden','Switzerland','Syria','Taiwan','Tajikistan','Tanzania','Thailand','Togo','Tokelau','Tonga','Transnistria','Trinidad and Tobago','Tunisia','Turkey','Turkmenistan','Turks and Caicos Islands',
                'Tuvalu','Uganda','Ukraine','United Arab Emirates','United Kingdom','United States','United States Virgin Islands','Uruguay','Uzbekistan','Vanuatu','Vatican City','Venezuela',
                'Vietnam','Wallis and Futuna','Yemen','Zambia','Zimbabwe'   
            ];

return {
    setUpAutoComplete : function() {
        $.getScript(typeAheadCDN,function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            if(jqxhr.status == 200) {
                $('#userCountry').typeahead({
                      hint: true,
                      highlight: true,
                      minLength: 1
                    },
                    {
                      name: 'states',
                      source: countryList
                    });
            }
        });           
    }
}
}();
```

I call `setUpAutoComplete` when DOM had fully loaded.

```
$(function(){ // When DOM has loaded
   Countries.setUpAutoComplete();
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control reg-dcf" id="userCountry" />
```

What mistake am I making here?

Answer (score 0):

In the input text tag you miss to add class="typeahead" attribute, refer here https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Even jquery UI autocomplete function also works in the same way, this will show you the country name as and when you type in text box..

```
$(function () {
var countryList = [
            'Afghanistan','Albania','Algeria','American Samoa','Andorra','Angola','Anguilla','Antigua and Barbuda','Argentina','Armenia','Aruba','Australia','Austria','Azerbaijan',
            'The Bahamas','Bahrain','Bangladesh','Barbados','Belarus','Belgium','Belize','Benin','Bermuda','Bhutan','Bolivia','Bosnia and Herzegovina','Botswana','Brazil','British Virgin Islands',
            'Brunei','Bulgaria','Burkina Faso','Burundi','Cambodia','Cameroon','Canada','Cape Verde','Cayman Islands','Central African Republic','Chad','Chile','China','Christmas Island',
            'Cocos Islands','Colombia','Comoros','Cook Islands','Costa Rica','Côte d\'Ivoire','Croatia','Cuba','Curaçao','Cyprus','Czech Republic','Democratic Republic of the Congo',
            'Denmark','Djibouti','Dominica','Dominican Republic','East Timor','Ecuador','Egypt','El Salvador','Equatorial Guinea','Eritrea','Estonia','Ethiopia','Falkland Islands',
            'Faroe Islands','Fiji','Finland','France','French Guiana','French Polynesia','Gabon','The Gambia','Georgia','Germany','Ghana','Gibraltar','Greece','Greenland','Grenada',
            'Guadeloupe','Guam','Guatemala','Guernsey','Guinea','Guinea-Bissau','Guyana','Haiti','Honduras','Hong Kong','Hungary','Iceland','India','Indonesia','Iran','Iraq','Ireland',
            'Isle of Man','Israel','Italy','Jamaica','Japan','Jersey','Jordan','Kazakhstan','Kenya','Kiribati','Kosovo','Kuwait','Kyrgyzstan','Laos','Latvia','Lebanon','Lesotho','Liberia',
            'Libya','Liechtenstein','Lithuania','Luxembourg','Macedonia','Madagascar','Malawi','Malaysia','Maldives','Mali','Malta','Marshall Islands','Martinique','Mauritania','Mauritius',
            'Mayotte','Mexico','Federated States of Micronesia','Moldova','Monaco','Mongolia','Montenegro','Montserrat','Morocco','Mozambique','Myanmar','Nagorno-Karabakh','Namibia','Nauru',
            'Nepal','Netherlands','New Caledonia','New Zealand','Nicaragua','Niger','Nigeria','Niue','Norfolk Island','North Korea','Northern Cyprus','Northern Mariana Islands','Norway',
            'Oman','Pakistan','Palau','Panama','Papua New Guinea','Paraguay','Peru','Philippines','Pitcairn Islands','Poland','Portugal','Puerto Rico','Qatar','Republic of the Congo',
            'Réunion','Romania','Russia','Rwanda','Sahrawi Arab Democratic Republic','Saint Barthélemy','Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha','Saint Kitts and Nevis','Saint Martin',
            'Saint Lucia','Saint Pierre and Miquelon','Saint Vincent and the Grenadines','Samoa','San Marino','São Tomé and Príncipe','Saudi Arabia','Senegal','Serbia','Seychelles','Sierra Leone',
            'Singapore','Sint Maarten','Slovakia','Slovenia','Solomon Islands','Somalia','South Africa','South Korea','South Sudan','Spain','Sri Lanka','Sudan','Suriname','Svalbard','Swaziland',
            'Sweden','Switzerland','Syria','Taiwan','Tajikistan','Tanzania','Thailand','Togo','Tokelau','Tonga','Transnistria','Trinidad and Tobago','Tunisia','Turkey','Turkmenistan','Turks and Caicos Islands',
            'Tuvalu','Uganda','Ukraine','United Arab Emirates','United Kingdom','United States','United States Virgin Islands','Uruguay','Uzbekistan','Vanuatu','Vatican City','Venezuela',
            'Vietnam','Wallis and Futuna','Yemen','Zambia','Zimbabwe'   
        ];            
        $("#userCountry").autocomplete({
            source: countryList                
        });
    });
```

for more details refer here https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight